# Can plusieurs mean "many people"?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Can *plusieurs* be a substantive pronoun meaning "many people"? For example,

> Il faut que tu parles avec plusieurs.
>
> = It is necessary that you talk with many people.

Or would you say it another way?

Comment: [...] plusieurs personnes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right word for plusieurs would be several. More than one. It doesn't necessarily mean many.